# css invert filer in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-filters

I have

```
BODY
{
-webkit-filter: invert(100%);
-moz-filter: invert(100%);
-ms-filter: invert(100%);
-o-filter: invert(100%);
filter: invert(100%);
}
```

and

```
.jpg
{
-webkit-filter: invert(0%) !important;
-moz-filter: invert(0%) !important;
-ms-filter: invert(0%) !important;
-o-filter: invert(0%) !important;
filter: invert(0%) !important;
}
```

This works in MIE. Chrome insists on inverting also the pictures with the jpg class.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Understanding CSS Filter Effects](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/):

> When a browser loads a web page it needs to apply styles, perform layout and then render the page so there's something to look at. Filters kick in after all those steps and just before the page is copied to the screen. What they do is take a snapshot of the rendered page as a bitmap image, then perform some graphics magic on the pixels in the snapshot and then draw the result over the top of the original page image.

You're applying a filter to the `body`, and the filter is applied to the whole element as a flattened image, not each child element individually, so you can't override the filter on a child like you're trying to do.

What you *can* do in your case is apply `invert(100%)` to the selector you want to show up as uninverted, because a double inverted image becomes normal again.

Comment: Thanks. You can override the filter on a child in MIE, like I mentioned. But if that is what W3C is recommending I don't know. I did think about doing the double thing for Chrome. I'll try that now.

Comment: Yep. That worked! Great step forward. :) It sadly also inverted the Facebook profile photos thumbs in Chrome. (Not in MIE). But this is way better than what I had. That Facebook Like button thing is almost impossible to customize anyways.

Comment: Do we know why there is talk about -moz-filter and -o-filter around, when, as far as I can see, there is no filter support in Firefox and Opera. Just a hope for what might soon work?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm confused about which browsers support it. [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) says it's only on WebKit, but the article in my answer says Firefox also. IE isn't mentioned in any of them, but if you're seeing results maybe it's triggering their old, deprecated filters.

Comment: Nice theory about triggering Microsoft's deprecated filters. Could be it. People do keep claiming it forks in FF. For instance here: http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/4030964.htm. I also just found out there's yet another prefix: -khtml for Konqueror.

Comment: The html5rocks.com article have actually applied filters to the images before embedding them, so little proof there.

Comment: Yea, those are as examples of what it _should_ look like. They link to some demo pages at the end of the article.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the first statement.
To fix it use the following

```
*
{
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}

.jpg
{
    -webkit-filter: invert(0%) !important;
    -moz-filter: invert(0%) !important;
    -ms-filter: invert(0%) !important;
    -o-filter: invert(0%) !important;
    filter: invert(0%) !important;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know * could stand alone like that in CSS. Also, it didn't work for me. But your answer did get me to try to fix this issue again, and it seems to be working in all browsers now. Thanks yo.

Comment: It's recommended to stay away from the "universal selector" due to performance (especially with no additional selectors), this could also get wonky as well because each element will get its own filter so you may have filters on filters where some invert the previous filter. I would recommend you use it on the `html` selector to avoid positioning issues and to have a single filter. You could then just do `invert(100%)` on the `.jpg` selector to reverse the original invert.