# CSS Filter invert rule breaking fixed position on Chrome 68

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position, css-filters

I'm on Chrome 68.

Whenever I have `filter: invert(xxx);` on the `<body>`, anything positioned as `fixed` doesn't stick to the screen, it scrolls with everything.

---

***Demo with `filter: invert(xxx);`***

```css
body{
  height: 8000px;
  filter: invert(0.85);
}

div{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

***Demo without `filter: invert(xxx);`***

```css
body{
  height: 8000px;
}

div{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**EDIT: Works fine on Chrome 67, but not on Chrome 68.**

Comment: Interesting bug, i found it on FireFox (61.0.1), only...

Comment: I'm using Chrome, though.

Comment: Chrome 67.0.3396.99: working perfectly... Chrome 68.0.3440.75: bug appears...

Comment: I can't spot the difference between these two snippets. Both looks same(except the filter).

Comment: It seems to be a Chrome 68 bug, I tested it on Chrome 67 and it works fine. I'm adding the tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351948/css-invert-filer-in-chrome  this might help you

Comment: @Viira It doesn't have anything to do with my issue, unfortunately.

Comment: Oops! We'll find a better solution then, wait.

Comment: @Viira In the first example position:fixed doesn't work, make sure that you have Chrome 68

Comment: It doesn't work on firefox too @PascalGoldbach

Comment: using `filter` seems to be the issue - also experiencing this with adding dropshadows via `filter`. `filter` creates a new position context for children with `position: fixed` at any sub-body level

Comment: added a bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=877015

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like a bug on Google Chrome 68, but you can solve this using the `<html>` element instead of the `<body>` element:

```css
html {
  height: 8000px;
  filter: invert(0.85);
}
div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Note:** In case only `top` and `left` is set to 0 the element doesn't stay fixed on scroll. But if you add `bottom: 0;` the element stay fixed again.

---

I also compared the styles before (Chrome 67) and after (Chrome 68) the update and the following values changed on the same example (with `filter`):

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| Chrome 67     | Chrome 68       |
+---------------+-----------------+
| bottom: 97px; | bottom: 7898px; |
| right: 526px; | right: 510px;   |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Adding it to the `<html>` seems to fix it indeed !

Comment: It still keeps scrolling on firefox :/

Comment: @Viira - fixed but weird :D (see update)

Comment: I ain't lying bro T_T it's not working on Firefox. @SebastianBrosch

Comment: @Viira - possible only checked on chrome ;)

Comment: Not a bug. It just creates a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937920/927631)